# AWS Cognito Batch Query

Tags: amazon-cognito

Is it possible to query AWS cognito with a list of user ids? Let's say i have user ids List : **userid1,userid2,userid3,userid4,userid5,userid6**

I know how to get an users one by one using their id or email address, but I was wondering if it is possible to get the users in a batch query using their ids or emails.

I use golang, but I can use any other language thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm surprised that AWS Cognito does not give you such minimum degree of query power.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it directly, but maybe you could use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html with a filter condition, but it has this limitation:

> You can only search for the following standard attributes:
>
> - username (case-sensitive)
> - email
> - phone_number
> - name
> - given_name
> - family_name
> - preferred_username
> - cognito:user_status (called Status in the Console) (case-insensitive)
> - status (called Enabled in the Console) (case-sensitive)
> - sub
>
> Custom attributes are not searchable.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly filter won't work, because it only supports 2 conditions: "=" and "begin with".

I guess you have to use promise.all()